# populate treeview with elemens from a list

Tags: c#

I have a list of persons, each person has a name and a category (e.g. friends, colleagues, others). I want to add each person from the list in treeview.

```
List<person> agenda = new List<person>();
 for (int i = 0; i < agenda.Count; i++)
    {
        person p = agenda.ElementAt(i);

       treeView1.Nodes[p.getCategory()].Nodes.Add(p.getName());
```

or

```
if(p.getCategory()=="friends")
     treeView1.Nodes["friends"].Nodes.Add(p.getName());
else if (p.getCategory() == "colleagues")
     treeView1.Nodes["colleagues"].Nodes.Add(p.getName());
else (p.getCategory() == "others") treeView1.Nodes["others"].Nodes.Add(p.getName());
}
```

I tried this, but it adds all elements to the first category.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will be of any help, but instead I am will try this (un-tested)

```
foreach(Person p in agenda)
{
    treeView1.BeginUpdate();
    treeView1.Nodes.Add(p.getCategory());
    treeView1.Nodes[p.getCategory()].Nodes.Add(p.getName());
    treeView1.EndUpdate();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but doesn't work
I get a NullReferenceException -Object reference not set to an instance of an object.